# ImportError: object file libiconv.so.2 missing

Tags: scrapy

I was trying out QuotesSpider example given in docs (page# 5, [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scrapy/1.2/scrapy.pdf)), but am having a hard time to get it running. I installed scrapy from conda in the root environment. I am on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit machine. As soon as I run the given code snippet with the following command:

```
$ scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json
```

I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    import scrapy.cmdline
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/home/rip/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

As apparent, an object file seems to be missing. Do I have to build scrapy from source, or is there an alternative?